# How to show that using 'cache' in a Python program is more efficient?

Tags: python, caching

The program uses two ways to calculate the Collatz Conjecture sequence, I want to show that the method using cache, rather than starting from scratch is more efficient - uses fewer processes.  I have tried using the time module and it keeps giving inconsistent results - sometimes the cache method appears to be slower than calculating the sequence from scratch.

```
cache = {}

def in_cache(n):
    if n in cache.keys():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def calculate_collatz(n):
    count = 0
    collatz_sequence = "N: " + str(n)
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = (3 * n) + 1
        count += 1
        collatz_sequence += " -> {}".format(n)
        

    return (collatz_sequence, count)
    
        
def collatz(n):
    if in_cache(n):
        print("Using cache...")
        
        return cache[n]
    else:
        print("Calculating from scratch...")
        result = calculate_collatz(n)
        cache[n] = result
        return result

choice = ""
while choice != 'Q':
    #print('The cache: ', cache)
    choice = input("Enter an integer to calculate the Collatz Conjecture sequence. Enter Q to quit\n")

    try:
        n = int(choice)
        print(collatz(n))
       
    except:
        print("You did not enter a whole number")
```

Comment: `import time`, at the start do `time1 = time.time()`, at the end do `time2 = time.time()` and then do `print(time2 - time1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the execution time of the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878770/how-to-get-the-execution-time-of-the-code)

Comment: Using "cache" in your code makes it faster ONLY when the user re-enters a number more than once. You can't measure the time of something that isn't determined like this. In this case, you should use complexity analysis to prove that rigorously.

Comment: How would I go about using complexity analysis using my example?